# Send JSON to server side using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have a html form and I am making the json object as:

```
var JSobObject=
    '{"name":"'+personObject.GetPersonName()+
    '","about":"'+personObject.GetAbout()+
    '","contact":"'+personObject.GetPersonContact()+'"}';
```

(Here `personObject` holds the form data)

trying to post it to Server.php as:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
//var url = "organizePeople.php?people=" + escape(people.toJSONString());
xmlhttp.open("POST","ServerJSON.php?person="+JSobObject,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(JSobObject);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

I am not getting any response from the server.php In my server i am doing this

```
$person = $_POST['person']; 
$objArray = json_decode($person);
print_r($objArray);
```

Can anyone help me that what I am doing wrong? I am in the learning stage. Just using JS/AJAX I want to prepare JSON and send it to server and get the response of the object datas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I prefer that, you do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It is JavaScript based library to do things (like this) easier.

```
$.post({
  url: "Server.php",
  data: JSobObject,
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function(msg) {
  alert(msg);
});
```

You need to download jQuery - of course - to get code to working!

Answer (score 0):

2 thoughts I'm having.
First of all, I'd sugest you move the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange assigment to above the send() call.

Secondly, have you checked with firebug if you're getting any reponse?
Have you tried calling your php page directly, rather than through ajax?

Comment: code is not entering the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
} section

Answer (score 0):

You should check the rawpost from php first,
`$_POST` maybe fill slashes Automatedly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but probably you'll want something like

```
$data = json_decode($_POST, true);
$person = $data['person'];
```

The reason being you're post data is entirely a JSON encoded text string, so you'll need to decode the entire post before you can access the data separately.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code will help you**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Servlet Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.serializeJSON.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>Submit form Data to Database in JSON</h1>


</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
<h3>Enter the Details : </h3>
 <form name="myform" id="myform"> 
<div class="form-group">
<label for="fullName">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="subject">Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="mark">Mark:</label>
<input type="number" name="mark" class="form-control">
</form>
</div>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success " id="submitform">Submit</button>




</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitform").click(function(e)
{
var MyForm = JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeJSON());
console.log(MyForm);
 $.ajax(
 {
 url : "<your url>",
 type: "POST",
 data : MyForm,

 });
 e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action

});
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```